# Search attachments in custom post type only

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type with custom taxonomies, basically a gallery post type.  I want to be able to search through the images in the post type.  I have created a custom search query for post type and attachments and it doesn't work quite well.  I get duplicate search results for some images.  Since the image is part of a CPT entry but also exist in the media library.  Is there a way to search attachments from a CPT only?

```
<?php

Class SMGallerySearch {

private $query_instance;

public function __construct(){
    add_filter( 'posts_join', array( &$this, 'terms_join' ) );
    add_filter( 'posts_search', array( &$this, 'search_where' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'posts_request', array( &$this, 'distinct' ) );
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'search_query' ) );
    add_filter( 'attachment_link', array( &$this, 'the_search_attachment_link' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', array( &$this, 'the_search_excerpt' ) );
}

public function terms_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! empty( $this->query_instance->query_vars['s'] ) ) {

        // searching custom taxonomies
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( array( 'sm_gallery_item', 'attachment' ) );
        foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
            $on[] = "ttax.taxonomy = '" . addslashes( $taxonomy )."'";
        }

        // build our final string
        $on = ' ( ' . implode( ' OR ', $on ) . ' ) ';
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS trel ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = trel.object_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS ttax ON ( " . $on . " AND trel.term_taxonomy_id = ttax.term_taxonomy_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms AS tter ON (ttax.term_id = tter.term_id) ";
    }
    return $join;
}


/**
 * Creates the list of search keywords from the 's' parameters
 *
 * @since 1.8.7
 */
public function get_search_terms() {
    global $wpdb;
    $s = isset( $this->query_instance->query_vars['s'] ) ? $this->query_instance->query_vars['s'] : '';
    $sentence = isset( $this->query_instance->query_vars['sentence'] ) ? $this->query_instance->query_vars['sentence'] : false;
    $search_terms = array();

    if ( !empty( $s ) ) {
        // added slashes screw with quote grouping when done early, so done later
        $s = stripslashes( $s );
        if ( $sentence ) {
            $search_terms = array( $s );
        } else {
            preg_match_all( '/".*?("|$)|((?<=[\\s",+])|^)[^\\s",+]+/', $s, $matches );
            $search_terms = array_map( create_function( '$a', 'return trim($a, "\\"\'\\n\\r ");' ), $matches[0] );
        }
    }
    return $search_terms;
}


/**
 * Add where clause to the search query
 *
 * @since 1.8.7
 */
public function search_where( $where, $wp_query ) {

    $this->query_instance = &$wp_query;
    global $wpdb;

    $searchQuery = $this->search_default();

    $searchQuery .= $this->build_search_categories();

    if ( $searchQuery != '' ) {
        $where = preg_replace( '#\(\(\(.*?\)\)\)#', '(('.$searchQuery.'))', $where );

    }
    return $where;
}


/**
 * Search for terms in default locations like title and content
 * replacing the old search terms seems to be the best way to
 * avoid issue with multiple terms
 *
 * @since 1.8.7
 */
public function search_default(){
    global $wpdb;

    $not_exact = empty( $this->query_instance->query_vars['exact'] );
    $search_sql_query = '';
    $seperator = '';
    $terms = $this->get_search_terms();

    // if it's not a sentance add other terms
    $search_sql_query .= '(';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $search_sql_query .= $seperator;

        $esc_term = esc_sql( $term );
        if ($not_exact) {
            $esc_term = "%$esc_term%";
        }

        $like_title = "($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '$esc_term')";
        $like_post = "($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '$esc_term')";

        $search_sql_query .= "($like_title OR $like_post)";

        $seperator = ' AND ';
    }

    $search_sql_query .= ')';
    return $search_sql_query;
}


/**
 * Create the search categories query
 *
 * @since 1.8.7
 */
public function build_search_categories() {
    global $wpdb;
    $vars = $this->query_instance->query_vars;

    $s = $vars['s'];
    $search_terms = $this->get_search_terms();
    $exact = isset( $vars['exact'] ) ? $vars['exact'] : '';
    $search = '';

    if ( ! empty( $search_terms ) ) {
        // Building search query for categories slug.
        $n = ( $exact ) ? '' : '%';
        $searchand = '';
        $searchSlug = '';
        foreach ( $search_terms as $term ) {
            $term = addslashes_gpc( $term );
            $searchSlug .= "{$searchand}(tter.slug LIKE '{$n}".sanitize_title_with_dashes( $term )."{$n}')";
            $searchand = ' AND ';
        }
        if ( count( $search_terms ) > 1 && $search_terms[0] != $s ) {
            $searchSlug = "($searchSlug) OR (tter.slug LIKE '{$n}".sanitize_title_with_dashes( $s )."{$n}')";
        }
        if ( ! empty( $searchSlug ) )
            $search = " OR ({$searchSlug}) ";

        // Building search query for categories description.
        $searchand = '';
        $searchDesc = '';
        foreach ( $search_terms as $term ) {
            $term = addslashes_gpc( $term );
            $searchDesc .= "{$searchand}(ttax.description LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
            $searchand = ' AND ';
        }
        $sentence_term = esc_sql( $s );
        if ( count( $search_terms ) > 1 && $search_terms[0] != $sentence_term ) {
            $searchDesc = "($searchDesc) OR (ttax.description LIKE '{$n}{$sentence_term}{$n}')";
        }
        if ( ! empty( $searchDesc ) )
            $search = $search." OR ({$searchDesc}) ";
    }
    return $search;
}

public function distinct( $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! empty( $this->query_instance->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
        if ( strstr( $query, 'DISTINCT' ) ) {}
        else {
            $query = str_replace( 'SELECT', 'SELECT DISTINCT', $query );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}

public function search_query( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_search )
        return $query;

    if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) && 'sm_gallery_item' == $query->get( 'post_type' ) ) {

        $post_types = $query->get( 'post_type' );
        if ( $post_types && 'sm_gallery_item' == $post_types )
            $post_types = array( 'sm_gallery_item', 'attachment' );

        $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );

        /**
         * Add post status "inherit" (for attachments) since WP only searches "publish"
         */
        $post_status = $query->get( 'post_status' );
        if ( ! $post_status || 'publish' == $post_status )
            $post_status = array( 'publish', 'inherit' );

        if ( is_array( $post_status ) )
            $post_status[] = 'inherit';

        $query->set( 'post_status', $post_status );

        return $query;

    }

 }


}
```

Comment: I do not think this will be possible because WordPress Media has one to many relation. One media can belong to many page/post (types).

Comment: Can you update your question with the search query you are using to filter the attachments belonging to a post type? May be if someone else has an idea he may help you.

Comment: I updated the question to include the search class I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've cracked it. Replace the top 14 lines of code with

Class SellMediaSearch {

```
private $query_instance;

/**
 * Init
 */
public function __construct(){
    add_filter( 'posts_join', array( &$this, 'terms_join' ) );
    add_filter( 'posts_search', array( &$this, 'search_where' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'posts_request', array( &$this, 'distinct' ) );
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', array( &$this, 'search_query' ) );
    add_filter( 'attachment_link', array( &$this, 'the_search_attachment_link' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', array( &$this, 'the_search_excerpt' ) );
    add_filter( 'posts_where' , array( &$this, 'posts_where' ));
}


public function posts_where( $where ) {

    global $wpdb;
    if( is_search() ) {
                    $where .= ' AND ( post_type = \'sell_media_item\' OR ( post_type = \'attachment\' AND post_parent !=  0 ) ) ';
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Needs testing, but initially works for me. See github for more comments.